# if $2^x+5^y=2^y+5^x=\frac{7}{10}$

Tags: calculus

let $x,y$ such
$$2^x+5^y=2^y+5^x=\dfrac{7}{10}$$

prove or disprove $x=y=-1$ is the only solution for the system.

My  try: since
$$2^x-2^y=5^x-5^y$$

But How can prove  or disprove  $x=y$?

Comment: Are $x,y$ assumed to be integers or real numbers?

Answer (score 10):

**Here is my idea of proving it:**

1. For $x=y=-1$, you can verify that $2^{-1}+5^{-1}=0.7$
2. In order to refute any other possible solution where $x=y$:

   - You can prove that $f(x)=2^x+5^x$ is monotonously increasing
   - Do it by showing that $f'(x)=2^x\ln2+5^x\ln5$ is always positive
3. In order to refute any other possible solution where $x \neq y$:

   - You have the following two equations:

     - $5^y=0.7-2^x$
     - $2^y=0.7-5^x$
   - Write down each equation as a simple function:

     - $y=\log_5(0.7-2^x)$
     - $y=\log_2(0.7-5^x)$
   - Prove that if $x \neq -1$, then the functions are not equal:

     - Prove that if $x>-1$, then $\log_2(0.7-5^x)>\log_5(0.7-2^x)$
     - Prove that if $x<-1$, then $\log_2(0.7-5^x)<\log_5(0.7-2^x)$

**Here is the graph of both functions, intersecting at $(-1,-1)$**:

[image]

Comment: I want to emphasize that the method of point (3) only works because you can deduce (1) from (2) (i.e. the derivation used to go from (1) to (2) is *reversible*). Merely deducing (2) from (1) does not allow point (3) to work: you can merely deduce that *if* any solution has $x = -1$ then it must have $y = -1$ too.

Comment: You haven't shown why they aren't any solutions with $x<-1,y>-1$ or $x>-1,y<-1$. 4 and 5 both show the same thing, that there are no solutions in the upper right and lower left quadrants relative to the known intercept.

Answer (score 2):

If $(x,y)$ is a solution, then we have both $2^y=\frac7{10}-5^x$ and
$$
2^y = (5^y)^{\log2/\log5} = \big(\tfrac7{10}-2^x\big)^{\log2/\log5}.
$$
So define $f(x)=\frac7{10}-5^x$ and $g(x)=\big(\tfrac7{10}-2^x\big)^{\log2/\log5}$. We want to show that the only place $f$ and $g$ are equal is at $x=-1$; it suffices to show that $f'(x)<g'(x)$ everywhere (to the right of $x=\log_2(0.7)$), or equivalently that $f'(x)/g'(x)<1$.

A calculation shows that $f'(x)/g'(x) = I(x)D(x)$, where
$$
I(x) = \bigg(\frac{\log5}{\log2}\bigg)^2\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^x \quad\text{and}\quad D(x) = \left(\frac{7}{10}-2^x\right)^{1-\log2/\log5}
$$
are increasing and decreasing functions, respectively. One can thus show that $I(x)D(x) < 1$ on an interval $[a,b]$ by showing that $I(a)D(b)<1$. In this way, one can show separately on each of the intervals
$$
(-\infty,-1.65],\, [-1.65,-1.25],\, [-1.25,-1.05],\, [-1.05,-0.9],\, [-0.9,-0.75],\, [-0.75,\log_2(0.7)] 
$$
that $I(x)D(x) < 1$. (On the leftmost interval, use $I(x)D(x) < I(-1.65)\lim_{x\to-\infty} D(x)$.)

Comment: I think you meant to say "by showing that $I(b)D(a)\lt1$," not "$I(a)D(b)$" -- you want to use the two *biggest* values.

Answer (score 2):

Write $x=u-v$, $\>y=u+v$ and put $r:={5\over2}$. Then we have to solve the equations
$$2^{u-v}+5^{u+v}=5^{u-v}+2^{u+v}={7\over10}\ .$$
Dividing the first equation by $2^u$ we obtain
$$(s:=)\qquad 2^{-v} +r^u 5^v = r^u 5^{-v}+ 2^v\ ,$$
or
$$r^u(5^v-5^{-v})=2^v-2^{-v}\ .\tag{1}$$
Equation $(1)$ is obviously fulfilled when $v=0$ and $u$ is arbitrary. This corresponds to an arbitrary choice of $(x,y)$ on the line $x=y$ and leads together with the remaining equation to $x=y=-1$.

But this is not all: For given  $v\ne0$ equation $(1)$ determines a unique $u\in{\mathbb R}$ by means of
$$r^u={2^v-2^{-v}\over 5^v-5^{-v}}\ ,\tag{2}$$
and for this value of $u$ (an even function of $v$) we then get
$$s={1\over2}\bigl(2^v+2^{-v}+r^u(5^v+5^{-v})\bigr)={10^v-10^{-v}\over 5^v-5^{-v}}\ .$$
With the help of $(2)$ it follows that
$$2^u s=\left({2^v-2^{-v}\over 5^v-5^{-v}}\right)^{\!\log 2/\log r}\ {10^v-10^{-v}\over 5^v-5^{-v}}=: f(v)\ .$$

[image]

Plotting $f(v)$ one finds that it is minimal at $v=0$ and assumes the (limiting) value $0.756463$ there, which is $>{7\over10}$. It follows that there are no solutions of the original problem with $v\ne0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's $99\%$ of a proof.  Unfortunately I'm stuck on the final, crucial $1\%$.

**Edit**:  Having finally understood Greg Martin's answer, I now see how to get unstuck on the crucial $1\%$.  I'm **inserting** the rest of the proof at the pertinent point, but leaving the rest alone. **End edit**

Note that $2^x+5^y=2^y+5^x$ implies $5^y-2^y=5^x-2^x$, so let's start by considering the "helper" function $h(x)=5^x-2^x$ on $(-\infty,0)$, which is where any solutions to the OP's problem must lie (since ${7\over10}\lt1$).  It's easy to see that $h(x)$ is always negative for $x\lt0$, that $h(0)=0$, and that $\lim_{x\to-\infty}h(x)=0$.  Furthermore, $h$ has a single minimum:

$$h'(x)=(\ln5)5^x-(\ln2)2^x=0\implies x={\ln\ln5-\ln\ln2\over\ln5-\ln2}\approx-.91936$$

For convenience, let's call this value $c$.

The upshot of this is that the assumption $y\not=x$ for the equation $2^x+5^y=2^y+5^x$ implicitly defines a function $y(x)$ with $(c,0)$ as its domain and $(-\infty,c)$ as its range.

Consider now the function $f(x)=2^x+5^{y(x)}$ on the interval $(c,0)$.  The question is, is ${7\over10}$ in the range of this function?  Noting that $\lim_{x\to c}y(x)=c$ and $\lim_{x\to0}y(x)=-\infty$, we have $f(c)=2^c+5^c\approx.75646$ and $f(0)=1$.  Since ${7\over10}\lt.75646$, we will be finished *if* we can show that $f(x)=2^x+5^{y(x)}$ doesn't decrease too much from its value of $.75646$ at $x=c$ before it increases to its value of $1$ at $x=0$.

**Insertion**:  $f(x)$ is the sum of the *increasing* function $2^x$ and the *decreasing* function $5^{y(x)}$.  Much as in Greg Martin's answer, we can show that $f(x)\gt.7$ on an interval $[a,b]$ if we can show $2^a+5^{y(b)}\gt.7$.  Some careful calculation with the helper function $h(x)=5^x-2^x$ shows

$$\begin{align}
y(-.85)&\gt-1\\
y(-.75)&\gt-1.15\\
y(-.6)&\gt-1.37\\
y(-.5)&\gt-1.6
\end{align}$$

from which we have

$$\begin{align}
2^c+5^{y(-.85)}&\gt 2^{-.91936}+5^{-1}\approx.7287\\
2^{-.85}+5^{y(-.75)}&\gt 2^{-.85}+5^{-1.15}\approx.71189\\
2^{-.75}+5^{y(-.6)}&\gt 2^{-.75}+5^{-1.37}\approx.70486\\
2^{-.6}+5^{y(-.5)}&\gt 2^{-.6}+5^{-1.6}\approx.7359\\
2^{-.5}+5^{y(0)}&\gt2^{-.5}+0\approx.707
\end{align}$$

which is all we need to conclude that $f(x)\gt.7$ on $[c,0]$.  **End insertion**

In fact it seems likely that $f(x)$ doesn't decrease *at all* on $(c,0)$, but that's the $1\%$ I'm stuck on.  The most I can say is that $2^x+5^y=2^y+5^x$ implies

$$y'={(\ln5)5^x-(\ln2)2^x\over(\ln5)5^y-(\ln2)2^y}$$

and hence

$$\begin{align}
f'(x)&=(\ln2)2^x+(\ln5)y'5^y\\
&={(\ln5)^25^{x+y}-(\ln2)^22^{x+y}\over(\ln5)5^y-(\ln2)2^y}\\
&=\left((\ln5)5^{(x+y)/2}+(\ln2)2^{(x+y)/2}\right){(\ln5)5^{(x+y)/2}-(\ln2)2^{(x+y)/2}\over(\ln5)5^y-(\ln2)2^y}
\end{align}$$

In this last expression, the factor in front is clearly positive.  As for the rest of it the denominator is negative since $y=y(x)\lt c$.  We would also have a negative numerator (and hence a strictly increasing function $f$) if we could show that $(x+y(x))/2\lt c$ for all $x\in(c,0)$.  But again, I'm stuck.  I thought I'd post things anyway, in case someone can fill in the gaps.